# Any info on iOS 12.2's Airplay multi tasking?

Tags: ios, airplay

I've seen that iOS 12.2 has multitasking support for Airplay but can't find any mention of it in documentation as to how it works, is it automatic that the video will continue playing when you back out of a screen or switch apps or is there an API to hook into to define the behaviour or get notifications of events?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite, it applies for example when you airplay apple music/netflix etc. to apple tv. You then have the ability to watch other short/small videos on your iphone without interrupting the stream to apple tv.

Before this any video/audio played on your phone while airplay was streaming got hijacked by a new video/audio played. Say if you were airplaying netflix to apple tv and started a video in safari it would hijack the stream and show the safari video on apple tv instead.

My example above is still an issue even with this update. From what i found the short/small video/audio refers to stuff like imessage videos, whatsapp videos and voice messages. Everything else i tried still hijacks the airplay stream to apple tv.

I'm not sure if apple will open this up to implement on other apps and make irrelevant of file size or length. I would love to know the parameters of what video's hijacks a stream and what one's stay internal on iphone.

Video playback still stops when you back out of an app without airplay activated.

When i read the update i had hoped apple would have been taking a google chromecast approach to airplay streaming. But apple consistently disappoint me...

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm finding some new behaviour in 12.2. On 11.4 if I close my app while I'm airplaying a video to AppleTV it stops playing the video back on the TV and shows my home screen on both devices (goes back to mirroring instead of external playback). But on 12.2 if I do the same the video continues to play on the AppleTV, while I can continue to use my iOS device for other things.